# Rails ajax render partial returning blank

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, acts-as-commentable

I'm trying to enable ajax commenting in my app and I'm able to submit everything just fine but when I try to render the list of comments it renders blank. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_member!
before_filter :load_commentable
before_filter :find_member

def index
   redirect_to root_path
end

def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
end

def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.member = current_member
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
          format.json
          format.js
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
          format.json
          format.js
        end
    end 
end

def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.member == current_member || @commentable.member == current_member
          @comment.destroy
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back, alert: 'You can\'t delete this comment.' }
        end
    end 
end

private

def load_commentable
    klass = [Status, Medium, Project, Event, Listing].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
    @commentable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
end

def find_member
    @member = Member.find_by_user_name(params[:user_name])
end 

end
```

**statuses_controller**

```
def show
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @status
    @comments = @commentable.comments.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page]).per_page(15)
    @comment = Comment.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { redirect_to profile_path(current_member) }
      format.js
    end
end
```

**statuses/show.html.erb**

```
<% if member_signed_in? %>
    <div id="comm_form_wrap">
        <%= render "shared/comment_form" %>
    </div>

    <div id="comments_wrap comments_<%= @commentable.id %>">
        <%= render partial: "shared/comments", :collection => @comments, :as => :comment %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**shared/_comments.html.erb**

```
<div id="comment_<%= comment.commentable.id %>_<%= comment.id %>" class="comments">
    <div class="com_con">
        <%= Rinku.auto_link(comment.content).html_safe %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**comments/create.js.erb**

```
$("#comm_form_wrap").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/comment_form') %>");
$('#comment_box').val('');
$("#comments_<%= @commentable.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/comments', :collection => @comments, :as => :comment) %>")
```

When I inspect the browser console it shows this happening:

```
$("#comm_form_wrap").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/comment_form') %>");
$('#comment_box').val('');
$("#comments_<%= @commentable.id %>").html("")
```

****EDIT****

```
$("#comments_93").html("/n  <\/div>\n\n         <div class=\"com_con\">\n               testing\n           <\/div>\n       <\/div>\n\n")
```

Comment: in your browser console does it show that an ajax request is being sent? if it's sent then is it giving any errors?

Comment: Yes the request is being sent and there are no errors the comment area looks like it's being rendered but nothing actually appears

Comment: I think I know what's wrong but don't know what I need to do to correct this. `@comments` is defined in my show action in my `statuses_controller` but not defined in  my `comments_controller` where the create call is coming from. What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: You need to have @comments in your create action because thats from where you are calling your create.js.erb file

Comment: Yup that was it. But now something weird is happening. The partial isn't updating. It stopped rendering blank but now it's not rendering at all, but if I check my browser console it says it's rendering what I want.

Comment: open up your ajax request in developer console and post what it says, also make sure your ids are correct and yeah since you are using ids they should be unique on that particular page

Comment: Ok I edited the question with the output from the console. It shows that's it's rendering what I submit it's just nothing happens on screen. All my id's were correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem I solved this by defining the `@comments` variable in the controller that creates the action and calls the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The last line in your `create.js.erb` is referring to an `id` that doesn't exist in your HTML page. Change it to `#comments_wrap` and it'll be all good.

Comment: Sorry forgot to change it in my edit but the div does have that id. And I added @comments to my comments controller as well so it's no longer returning blank. It's just not doing anything at all. No errors, debugger shows the new comment, but no actual rendering going on.

Comment: I see that you added the id to the div. But it looks like you have two ids with a space in between. If that's the case, it won't work. Remove comments_wrap part from the id and the space too.

Comment: Yeah sorry but I had caught that just forgot to change it on here. Everything is working fine now.